# Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I want to display **AdMob** fullscreen ads within my game.
So I have downloaded the latest **GoogleMobileAds-v5.4.0** unity package for my game.

But to my surprise, I can't able to get real ads from **AdMob** though Test Ads working fine.

In XCode Log, I was getting this kind of error messages:
[image]

I have created a demo project, just to test ads and no collision with other plugins can occur but the result is the same.

From first to last, I was following this document to implement AdMob ads:
[Get Started Google AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start)

I have mostly read other threads that are posted for the same problem but I can't able to find something that becomes useful so I decided to create a separate question with full information provided.

Share your knowledge if you have any idea for this kind of problem.
One more thing, My AdMob account is not new, I was using it for last 6 months.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal thing as per AdMob person, no problem exists from the outside.
For your device, there is no stock of ads available to display so they are giving this kind of message.

Plus they stopped showing ads for their potential customers (apps or games) through AI algorithms so whoever investing in marketing can get more benefits so if your app doesn't have a large user-base then it may be possible, you will get fewer ads within your device.

This is what I understand from my experience with AdMob ads.

**EDIT:** Exact message from Google Ads that I received.
[image]

I hope now everything is clear to viewers :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How long did it take to display some ads in your game after published in the AppStore? My game is now published since about 38 hours but no ads are showing until now. And I also added my game earlier in AdMob with the option, that it’s not in the AppStore right now. But I don’t find any option to tell AdMob, that it’s now published. Is this a problem, or will AdMob find my game automatically? Thanks.

Comment: Though real ads are not coming I hope you satisfied with the test ads running. If test ads running properly then don't worry as processing time from AdMob gets completed, ads started coming into your application. Ads coming time is varies based on your application public interest.

Comment: @SebastianOrtmann I found the exact message that I received from Google Ads